# How to make a methode that responds to request with one second delay Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to have a methode that **responds to request with one second delay**.

Of course **compared to the previous request** from any IP

I think I should make a queue.

**I'm working with a web api that responds to request after one second delay if I send 2 request in one seond I get an error**

For more information:
I get a request from any user and after editing the request then send it to a web api but web api has a rule. That is each request must be delayed by one second

Comment: What do you really want to achieve?

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: What will happen if you got 100 concurrent request? so 100th request should wait for al-least 99 secs before process?

Comment: I don't see a question here. You want to do that, great! Thanks for sharing it with us; I guess.

Comment: I'm working with a web api that responds to request after one second delay if I send 2 request in one seond I get an error , and I should return json

Comment: Are you using a web farm or web garden?

Comment: Do you know what I mean by a web farm / garden? _If you don't know, be honest._

Comment: No I don't ....

Comment: OK, is your app going to run on multiple web servers, or just the one? If it runs on multiple web servers, is the one second delay rule within the context of one of the web servers, or across all of them? In other words, if Server 1 takes a request now, Server 1 needs to wait a second to process the second request. But what if Server 2 received it instead? Would it need to wait as well, or could it process it straight away?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you want to limit number of requests from a user per some specific period of time to increase throughput or performance of your service.
To achieve it, you should configure your IIS server:

1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager:

   Windows Server 2012 or later: Taskbar -> Server Manager -> Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

   Windows 8 or later: Windows + X -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. In the Connections pane, select the server name to add dynamic IP restrictions for the server, or expand Sites and then select a site to add dynamic IP restrictions for the site.
3. In the Home pane, double-click the IP Address and Domain Restrictions feature.
   In the Actions pane, click Edit Dynamic Restriction Settings.
4. In the Dynamic IP Restriction Settings dialog box, select Deny IP Address based on the number of requests over a period of time, enter the maximum number of requests, enter the time period (in milliseconds) that is used to determine the request rate, and then click OK.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/denybyrequestrate